# how to place a UIImageView in a particular area of a subView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, addsubview

I am woundering if there is a way of placing a UIImageView into a specific area of another view using **addSubview**

this is how my code currently looks, I am woundering how I would add the image to a particular spot of the view its being added to, say (0,0) top left.

this is what I am doing atm.

```
//...
jumpBar = [[JumpBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JumpBarViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            jumpBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0, (jumpBarHeight + 49.0), 320.0)];
            [jumpBarContainer addSubview:jumpBar.view];
            [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainer belowSubview:actionTabBar];  

            // Add jumpBar shade
                switch (jumpBarHeight) {
                    case 103:
                    {
                        NSLog(@"one row");
                        UIImageView *smlShader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1-row-top-bg.png"]];
                        [jumpBarContainer addSubview:smlShader]; // how do i add this to the top left of jumBarContainer?
                    }
//...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the UIImageView frame:

```
     UIImageView *smlShader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1-row-top-bg.png"]];
     smlShader.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); //Change the value of the frame
     [jumpBarContainer addSubview:smlShader];
```

Comment: perfect!!!! cant belive i didnt think of this.. its just i didnt know how it would work when adding to subview if it takes the co-ordinates of that view or not.